# Enzyme / Jest Error testing component render in React (TS)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've been having an odd issue with Jest/Enzyme testing on my react typescript app. For some reason it gives a syntax error even though this is following the official documentation, as well as input from several articles.

The Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import NavbarTop from "../components/navbar";
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('NavbarTop', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<NavbarTop />);
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
        // On the first run of this test, Jest will generate a snapshot file automatically.
    });
});
```

The folder structure. I have a named class and then an index with a default export.

[image: Tree]

The error log.

[image: The console error log]

Comment: You may need to include the contents of `navbar/index.ts` and `navbar/navbarTop.tsx`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JSX configured for Jest? Looks like you don't have support for JSX in Jest, which probably means this is a configuration issue. Have a look at configuring babel to support JSX in Jest.

Make sure you [read this tutorial](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react)